# Converting Python's bytes object to a string causes data inside html to disappear

Tags: python, web-scraping

I’m trying to read HTML content and extract only the data (such as the lines in a Wikipedia article). Here’s my code in Python:

```
import urllib.request
from html.parser import HTMLParser

urlText = []


#Define HTML Parser
class parseText(HTMLParser):
    def handle_data(self, data):
        print(data)
        if data != '\n':
            urlText.append(data)


def main():

    thisurl = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)"
    #Create instance of HTML parser (the above class)
    lParser = parseText()
    #Feed HTML file into parser. The handle_data method is implicitly called.
    with urllib.request.urlopen(thisurl) as url:
        htmlAsBytes = url.read()
    #print(htmlAsBytes)
    htmlAsString = htmlAsBytes.decode(encoding="utf-8")
    #print(htmlAsString)
    lParser.feed(htmlAsString)
    lParser.close()
    #for item in urlText:
        #print(item)
```

I do get the HTML content from the webpage and if I print the bytes object returned by the read() method, it looks like I receive all the HTML content of the webpage. However, when I try to parse this content to get rid of the tags and store only the readable data, I’m not getting the result I expect at all.

The problem is that in order to use the feed() method of the parser, one has to convert the bytes object to a string. To do that you use the decode() method, which receives the encoding with which to do the conversion. If I print the decoded string, the content printed doesn’t contain the data itself (the useful readable data I’m trying to extract). Why does that happen and how can I solve this?

Note: I'm using Python 3.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I would definitely recommend using BeautifulSoup instead of trying to parse the HTML yourself. https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Comment: Not sure what you expect. If I try to run your program I get what I expect. Of course, you also have all javascript, menu content etc. of the page. So the "useful readable data" might be more than you think? Also agree with Alden.

Comment: From what I understand, the handle_data method is supposed to give me only the data written between tags. The parsing is done in the background by the parser itself? I don't invent the wheel, only override the callback that's supposed to do the parsing for me. But the data I'm passing to the parser is faulty - try to run the program with the print(htmlAsString) line of code uncommented and you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, I eventually used beautifulsoup to do the job, as Alden recommended, but I still don't know why the decoding process mysteriously gets rid of the data.